# Cannot update..keep showing update syntax error!! help please

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm looking for a little help, this code isn't working as written.

```
string upstatus = "UPDATE memberlogin " +
                  "SET password = " + newpwtxtbox.Text + " " +
                  "where username = " + usernametxtbox.Text;

OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connect);
con.Open();

OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(upstatus, con);
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("updated!");

con.Close();
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't do SQL like that, basically. Use parameterized queries instead. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This is because strings are not quoted in your query.

Comment: Password is a reserved word and must be prefixed tabl1.password or bracketed [password]. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266

Comment: omg ...thank bro !!..its the password problem...finally !!.being doing so long..thank ya

Comment: If your column name is a reserved SQL word, enclose them in braces like `[password]`

Answer (score 1):

You are using MS-Access, in that case `PASSWORD` is a reserved keyword.
Use square brackets around it

```
string upstatus = "UPDATE memberlogin SET [password]= .....";
```

A part from this, never use string concatenation to build sql command, but always a parameterized query.

```
string upstatus = "UPDATE memberlogin SET password=? where username = ?";
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connect);
con.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(upstatus, con);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", newpwtxtbox.Text);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", usernmaetxtbox.Text );
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The string concatenation approach is well known to lead to Sql Injection attacks, but it still a weak kind of code because a single quote typed in the password or username textbox will wreak havoc with your string command resulting in an invalid syntax sent to your database engine.